# How to query a remote database with a powershell command?

Tags: sql, database, windows, powershell

I've done some research and I found the command "Invoke-Sqlcmd". I believe this is the command I want to use, but not which arguments. I've tried multiple things, but keep getting *"invoke-sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'Hello'"*. Here is some practice data:

```
    "Forehead" is the name of the server I am executing the PowerShell query from
    "Elbow" is the name of the server that is running the SQL database
    "Kitten" is the name of the database on "Elbow"
    "Fluid" is the name of the table I wish to query
    "Hello" is the username to log into "Elbow"
    "World" is the password to log into "Elbow"
    "Timmy" is the username to log into "Kitten"
    "Sticky" is the password to log into "Kitten"
    "SELECT * FROM Fluid" is the query I wish to run
```

With this information, from "Forehead" how can I execute the above query on Kitten? Is there more information I need?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the username, password, sql server and database to [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps).
 Then your query (nice namings... :-)) should work.

```
$ServerInstance = 'Elbow'
$Database = 'Kitten'
$Username = 'Timmy'
$Password = 'Sticky'
$Query = 'SELECT * FROM Fluid'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Username $Username -Password $Password -Query $Query
```